# Search within a user's answers

Tags: support, answers, search

Is there a way to search for text within a specific user's answers?  I can approximate this with google using the `site:stackoverflow.com`, but this will include text from any answers to questions that the user also answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: `user:userId is:answer` where userId is the id number of the user. You can find the id number in the user's profile link. It's the number between "/users/" and "/displayname".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but, for example, if I know I've given a stellar (of course) answer on something I use "search text userid:myuserid"

[image]

As [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra) pointed out in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285447/seach-within-a-users-answers#comment152039_285447), adding the "is:answer" filter will confine the search to your answers.

And the [Search Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) that [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) linked to in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285447/seach-within-a-users-answers#comment152038_285447) will be very helpful to you.

Comment: Considering the OP wants to search answers only, you'd also want the "is:answer" condition in there.

Comment: @kendra yes, thanks. I usually find what I need without that fairly quickly but it's a good idea.

Comment: It's a great idea, especially if you're searching a profile with lots of both questions and answers. :) If the profile doesn't have a lot of either, such as mine, then it's really not necessary.

Comment: Also, if you can't remember your own user ID, "user:me" will search all of your own posts.

Comment: Or if you can't remember `user:me`, if you go to your own profile, the search string `user:xxxxx` will already appear in the search box, so you just need to add the other parameters you want to look at

Comment: All good points. I usually just right click on my username on the right and open in a new tab

Answer (score 5):

If the built in search functionality does not suit your needs, and you need something more powerful, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Exporter](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

[Take this query for example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/282263/367420/):

```sql
select p.Id [Post Link]
from Posts p
where 
  p.OwnerUserId = ##UserID## and
  (p.Body like '%##SearchQuery##%' or p.Title like '%##SearchQuery##%')
```

Enter your UserId and a search query and you are on your way. If you know Sql you can expand on this for more advanced queries.

Note: this data is refreshed *every week*. It is not real-time data.