# Search through comments I made

Tags: support, comments, search

Is there a way to search for a text in the comments I made? It was months ago that I made a comment on an answer for a question, can't remember the question title. I came across a new point of view which could help the OP so I'm trying to find the question. I found [Search within a users answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285447/search-within-a-users-answers/285448#285448) but that seems to work for answers only, not the comments. I remember a few words I used in the comment I made so if there's a way to search f them I can find the comment, and the question.

Comment: only way I know of is Ctrl+f on here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3309109/artm?tab=activities&sort=comments

Comment: Nope, can't do it unfortunately. If you remember what was written in the comment then Google's not _too_ bad at tracking it down. Just include your username, and that of your interlocutor if possible in your search.

Comment: @Tanner I tired that but there are 45 pages of comments so I gave up after the 10th page.

Comment: @Ben That actually worked, thanks.3rd in the list. Used "artm keywords site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Glad to hear it @artm. Don't rely on it always working, but comments are indexed just like questions and answers so if you remember enough you have a good chance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Data Explorer is your friend! [Here is a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273888/search-inside-comments-of-specific-user-now-case-insensitive) letting you search within comments.

For example, you have posted [22 comments on Stack Overflow that contain "thanks" or "Thanks"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273888/search-inside-comments-of-specific-user?UserId=3309109&Text=thanks). :)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Shadow. The text I was searching for was "beat me to it", google search found it but not this data search. Try "artm beat me to it site:stackoverflow.com" on google, it's the 3rd entry for me, the data explorer doesn't find it.

Comment: @artm whoops, case matters by default. Fixed now. :)

Comment: @artm nope, MSO is a different site - and it will take a while before it reach SEDE anyway. :)

Comment: Nice edit with " that contain "thanks" or "Thanks"" :)

Comment: Actually it might also contain "tHanks" but I'm too lazy to write all possible combos. :-D

Comment: Sorry, not good enough Wizard, if you don't write all different combinations I'll revert my vote :)

Comment: Can't seem to run any queries. It always generates the error `The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context.`. Though your second link works.

Comment: @TLP probably related to the Stack Exchange downtime they had today, it's not specific to this query (trying to construct new query gives generic ASP.NET error page). The second probably works due to it being cached by others running it before.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see, well, guess I can try later. Thanks.

Comment: @TLP http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249675/cant-explore-stack-exchange-data-explorer-errors-trying-to-build-new-query-and (when it will be fixed, you can try again :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Cool. :)

Comment: Here's another one http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73775/search-my-own-comments.

Comment: @TLama yup, didn't think to search SEDE - honestly, in the few times I tried to search I always utterly failed so at some point I decided to simply write on my own whenever I can. :)

Comment: it won't accept my username(101is5). I get the error: "Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'is5'." Help?

Comment: @101is5 the original query look for user **id** not name, if you changed it to look for name, wrap it with single quotes, e.g. `... Where Name='101is5'`