# Search for a user who had commented on a post

Tags: discussion

I am searching for a user who had commented on my answer.

I tried in search bar as

```
user:me xyz
```

where "xyz" is username.

But I can't find any. I feel this is a must feature because I do visite chatrooms frequently, where I see some familiar faces. I need to know exactly on which post we had came to know each other, like so.

I am not sure to which extent it is possible to have a search for a someone else's post where myself and "xyz" had posted comments. (*I don't think it is possible but just asking, as a end user*)

Comment: If it is more than a week ago you might use [SEDE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286164/578411)

Comment: Google has helped me in the past, searching for my user name and the other guy's user name (plus perhaps some words you remember from the comment)

Comment: @Pekka웃 you are right, it did work. I searched in google like:  `mr_green xyz stackoverflow`