# How to I find a post that I recently commented on?

Tags: support, comments

I have an inbox and recent achievements. I can also see answers that I've made and questions that I have made as well. I really need to find a post that I visited recently, other than using my browser history or any other non-stackexchange form of information, to find my most recent comment.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286161/search-through-comments-i-made

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to your profile
2. Go to the "Activity" tab
3. Go to the "All Actions" section
4. Go to the "Comments" subsection
5. ???
6. Profit.

Easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your profile by clicking on your name, then go to All Actions.