# Search field inside our profile

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, search

When we using stack we always saw that duplicated Question or some duplicated question content will always added. We can close Duplicated Question with the close/flag option.

**Assumption** if question is new. And when we answering there are some new part to add and there are some content can just share link which i have answered in past. So to get the link i have to play through the all paginations to find where is that link exactly.

**Suggestion** If we have search bar in our profile, then we can search the content or link what we expect to load. Check image below

**Extending** requesting to add in Questions, Comments, Answers.

[image: 01]

Comment: Or, use the search with the `user:me` operator to only search for content you created... replace `me` with the user Id of whoever's content you are looking for.

Comment: Having a search for comments would be really nice.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks mate ;)

Comment: Explanation on how to search comments with data explorer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286161/search-through-comments-i-made